# OLED DISPLAY USING SPI

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

My display is not responding to this code. Help please

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_MOSI 10
#define OLED_CLK 9
#define OLED_DC 12
#define OLED_CS 13
#define OLED_RESET 11
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_MOSI,OLED_CLK,OLED_DC,OLED_CS,OLED_RESET);


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC);
  display.clearDisplay();

  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(30,30);
  display.print("Hello WOrld");
  display.display();
  }

  void loop(){

    }
```

Comment: what does this mean? `not responding`

Comment: There is no code, that would respond to user actions. It just displays hello world, nothing else.

Comment: sorry what i meant was that the display is not turning on. I ran the adafruit example and the display qorks fine. So is there a problem in the code? i copied this code from a youtube video

Answer (score 1):

Pin definitions in your code seem to be mixed up. If Adafruit example works fine with your setup, you should keep the pin definitions Adarfruit uses:

```
#define OLED_MOSI   9
#define OLED_CLK   10
#define OLED_DC    11
#define OLED_CS    12
#define OLED_RESET 13
```

Also, you are using a deprecated constructor. It is recommended to use a constructor which explicitly specifies display size.